# CSS: Show an element only when you hover over it

Tags: css

The following hides the element, but I cannot recover when I hover over it.
I've checked devtools to see that it **is indeed** rendered on the screen, I just can't see the contents of the div.

How do I make it so the div is visible only on hover?

```
.visible-on-hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible-on-hover:hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Elements with  `visibility: hidden;` don't receive any mouse events.

Comment: Consider using opacity: 0 and opacity: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with  `visibility: hidden;` don't receive any mouse events, so `:hover` never triggers on such an element.

Instead of `visibility`, you can work with `opacity`:

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.visible-on-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.visible-on-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="visible-on-hover">visible only on hover</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not hover, focus or select a hidden element.
you can use `opacity`

```
.visible-on-hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.visible-on-hover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```